# How to match face in python

Tags: python, opencv, facial-identification

I am developing a system where the user at the time of registration will take a photo of the face.
Then this user will try to authenticate, using the face (just like on the iPhone X).
Which library do I use for this?
I want to make a 1: N match.
Is there a pattern for extracting minutiae from a face, as in digital biometrics?
I found this lib https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition, but I'm in doubt if it is meant to be used for user authentication.
If there is an online or offline service that does this, it will also help me.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [DeepFace](https://pypi.org/project/deepface/), they reference several possible models you can use including: VGG-Face , Google FaceNet, OpenFace and Facebook DeepFace.  Read up on them and find the best one for your application.

Comment: The both Google FaceNet and VGG-Face overperform wrapped by the deepface package based on my experiments.